# value in an array doesn't seem to be incremented after a for loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I know for a fact that the if statement `if ( (roll == i) && (result == true) )` is true many times during the 2500 iterations but when I output `winRolls[1]` or any other index of `winRolls` after the higher level for loop completes its 2500 iterations, the value of `winRolls[1]` and every other index always has a maximum value of 1.  Does this have something to do with a characteristic of c++ arrays or am I missing something else?

```
int winRolls[10]      
for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        if ( (roll == j) && (result == true) )
        {
            winRolls[roll] = winRolls[roll] + 1;
        }
}
cout << winRolls[1] << endl;
cout << winRolls[2] << endl; 
cout << winRolls[3] << endl;
```

Comment: You're never modifying `roll` in your code sample, so you're always incrementing the same array element and, since we don't know the initial value of `roll`, we cannot tell which element it is. Also keep in mind that array indices are zero-based in C++.

Comment: What's the value of result initially??

Comment: also roll is not initialised.

Comment: Just taking a quick look, but did you intentionally start j at 1?  c (and c++) arrays are indexed at 0.

Comment: Incomplete code, and, never say "I know for a fact that a statement is true", test it or show us some data ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few problems.

`winRolls` size is `[10]` and you are accessing it based on `i` (instead of `j`, which has correct limit for `winRolls`). If `roll == i` is `true` for say `1000` then you are accessing out of array range. Which will not help you getting desired output as well as you enter an **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing `winRolls`? If you do not initialize but increment its contents anyway, you might end up with garbage values (values that are different in each run of the program). Also, how will `roll == i` be true many times during the 25000 iterations? Unless you are updating the value of `roll` (which I do not see in the code), this inner loop will execute either only once or maybe never depending on what value `roll` has.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cout << winRolls[roll] << endl;` at the end.

You're incrementing the value in `winRolls[roll]` every time.

It looks like the code here is right. Your problem may lie elsewhere in your code.